# Fetch only those part in dictionary of dictionary which contains particular string in value

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having similar kind of code

```
{
    'global': 
    {
        'www.test1.com': ['x', 'y'],
        'www.test2.com': ['x', 'y'],
        'www.test3.com': ['x'],
        'www.test4.com': ['x', 'y'],
        'www.test5.com': ['x']
    },
    'private': 
    {
        'www.test6.com': ['m', 'n'],
        'www.test7.com': ['n'],
        'www.test8.com': ['m']
    }
}
```

where my desired output is this:

```
{
    'private': 
    {
        'www.test6.com': ['m', 'n'],
         'www.test7.com': ['n'],
    }
}
```

Based on 'n' I have to achieve the above output.
Basically where ever 'n' is present I have to show that part. If 'n' is there in 'global' part I need to fetch that particular combination as well.

like

Input:

```
{
    'global': 
    {
        'www.test1.com': ['x', 'n'],
        'www.test2.com': ['x', 'y'],
        'www.test3.com': ['x'],
        'www.test4.com': ['x', 'y'],
        'www.test5.com': ['n']
    },
    'private': 
    {
        'www.test6.com': ['m', 'n'],
        'www.test7.com': ['n'],
        'www.test8.com': ['m']
    }
}
```

then output should be like:

```
{
    'global': 
    {
        'www.test1.com': ['x', 'n'],
         'www.test5.com': ['n']
    },
    'private': 
    {
        'www.test6.com': ['m', 'n'],
         'www.test7.com': ['n'],
    }
}
```

How to achieve this output with given kind of code in small and good code.

Comment: Is the dictionary structure always the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dictionary comprehensions:

```
>>> new_d={key:dict(filter(lambda x:'n' in x[1], value.items())) for key, value in d.items() if dict(filter(lambda x:'n' in x[1], value.items()))}
```

Sample runs:

```
>>> d={
...     'global': 
...     {
...         'www.test1.com': ['x', 'n'],
...         'www.test2.com': ['x', 'y'],
...         'www.test3.com': ['x'],
...         'www.test4.com': ['x', 'y'],
...         'www.test5.com': ['n']
...     },
...     'private': 
...     {
...         'www.test6.com': ['m', 'n'],
...         'www.test7.com': ['n'],
...         'www.test8.com': ['m']
...     }
... }
>>> new_d={key:dict(filter(lambda x:'n' in x[1], value.items())) for key, value in d.items() if dict(filter(lambda x:'n' in x[1], value.items()))}
>>> new_d
{'global': {'www.test5.com': ['n'], 'www.test1.com': ['x', 'n']}, 'private': {'www.test6.com': ['m', 'n'], 'www.test7.com': ['n']}}
```

Running the same code over your 1st example:

```
>>> d={
...     'global': 
...     {
...         'www.test1.com': ['x', 'y'],
...         'www.test2.com': ['x', 'y'],
...         'www.test3.com': ['x'],
...         'www.test4.com': ['x', 'y'],
...         'www.test5.com': ['x']
...     },
...     'private': 
...     {
...         'www.test6.com': ['m', 'n'],
...         'www.test7.com': ['n'],
...         'www.test8.com': ['m']
...     }
... }
>>> new_d={key:dict(filter(lambda x:'n' in x[1], value.items())) for key, value in d.items() if dict(filter(lambda x:'n' in x[1], value.items()))}
>>> new_d
{'private': {'www.test6.com': ['m', 'n'], 'www.test7.com': ['n']}}
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked. Bingo

Answer (score 0):

You can search for 'n' in each list using this:

```
a = {
    'global': 
    {
        'www.test1.com': ['x', 'n'],
        'www.test2.com': ['x', 'y'],
        'www.test3.com': ['x'],
        'www.test4.com': ['x', 'y'],
        'www.test5.com': ['n']
    },
    'private': 
    {
        'www.test6.com': ['m', 'n'],
        'www.test7.com': ['n'],
        'www.test8.com': ['m']
    }
}

b = {'global': {}, 'private': {}}

for i, j in a.items():
    for k, l in j.items():
        if 'n' in l:
            b[i][k] = l

finalDict = {i:j for i,j in b.items() if j} # To remove empty key/values
```

Or using dictionary comprehension:

```
a = {
    'global': 
    {
        'www.test1.com': ['x', 'n'],
        'www.test2.com': ['x', 'y'],
        'www.test3.com': ['x'],
        'www.test4.com': ['x', 'y'],
        'www.test5.com': ['n']
    },
    'private': 
    {
        'www.test6.com': ['m', 'n'],
        'www.test7.com': ['n'],
        'www.test8.com': ['m']
    }
}

b = {'global': {i:j for i,j in a['global'].items() if 'n' in j}, 'private': {i:j for i,j in a['private'].items() if 'n' in j}}

finalDict = {i:j for i,j in b.items() if j} # To remove empty key/values
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using defaultdicts, it works for both examples.

```
    from collections import defaultdict

    d = {
        'global': 
        {
            'www.test1.com': ['x', 'y'],
            'www.test2.com': ['x', 'y'],
            'www.test3.com': ['x'],
            'www.test4.com': ['x', 'y'],
            'www.test5.com': ['x']
        },
        'private': 
        {
            'www.test6.com': ['m', 'n'],
            'www.test7.com': ['n'],
            'www.test8.com': ['m']
        }
    }

    def n_finder(d):

        my_dict = defaultdict(dict)

        for key, value in d.items():
            for val in value:
                if "n" in value[val]:
                    my_dict[key][val] = value[val]

        return my_dict

    # Output

    defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'private': {'www.test6.com': ['m', 'n'], 'www.test7.com': ['n']}})
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried, It worked. But I find better and small code solution for the same problem provided by @ritest93.

Comment: No worries. If you struggle with dictionaries then I suggest implementing longer solutions at first. It will help you get better at them.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I tried the same. (thumsup)

Answer (score 0):

If your `dict` has a static structure, you can use dict comprehensions like other answers.

If your dict has a complex structure, you can use my function here:

```
import copy

def dict_search(src_dict, search_str):

   def rebuild_dict(original_dict, search_str):
      result_dict = copy.deepcopy(original_dict)
      for key, value in original_dict.iteritems():
         if isinstance(value, dict):
            ret_value = clean_dict(value, search_str)
            if not ret_value:
               result_dict.pop(key)
            else:
               result_dict[key] = ret_value
         elif isinstance(value, list):
            if search_str not in value:
               result_dict.pop(key)
         elif search_str != value:
            result_dict.pop(key)
      return result_dict


   if not isinstance(src_dict, dict):
      raise TypeError("src_dict must be a dict")

   return rebuild_dict(src_dict, search_str)
```

Test it:

```
a= {
    'global':
    {
        'www.test1.com': ['x', 'n'],
        'www.test2.com': ['x', 'y'],
        'www.test3.com': ['x'],
        'www.test4.com': ['x', 'y'],
        'www.test5.com': ['n']
    },
    'private':
    {
        'www.test6.com': ['m', 'n'],
        'www.test7.com': ['n'],
        'www.test8.com': ['m']
    }
}

print(dict_search(a, 'x'))
```

Output:

```
{'global': {   'www.test1.com': ['x', 'n'], 'www.test5.com':['n']},
 'private': {   'www.test6.com': ['m', 'n'], 'www.test7.com': ['n']}}
```